# X12 Reader (C#) Performance

Tags: c#, performance

@Hans Passant - This question goes into much much more detail of the problem that I did not receive an answer to in the previous post. All I want is help on this problem and I keep getting flagged on technicalities. This is ridiculous. I've tried my best to be very detailed and specific on this question that is an UNANSWERED question. If action needs to be taken, please delete my previous question.

@Hans Passant - You have effectively killed all discussion on my question. Thanks! A moderators job is supposed to be to facilitate useful discussion, not kill it with technicalities. Now both of my questions are effectively dead and I have no answer, and on top of all that! The kicker is that if I post another question it will be marked as duplicate!

Is there any way that I can improve the performance of my x12_reader? The main functions that seem to be the bottlenecks are read_line() and get_element() they are both called upwards of millions of times.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace X12ReprocessApp {

public class segment {
    public String line_text = "";
    public String loop_id = "";
    public String id = null;

    ///<summary>
    ///Returns a string containing the element from the current segment.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="element_number">The element number that you want to return</param>
    public String get_element(int element_number) {
        int count = 0;
        int start_index = 0;
        int end_index = 0;
        int current_index = 0;

        while (count < element_number && current_index != -1) {
            current_index = line_text.IndexOf(x12_reader.element_delimiter, start_index);
            start_index = current_index + 1;
            count++;
        }

        if (current_index != -1) {
            end_index = line_text.IndexOf(x12_reader.element_delimiter, start_index);
            if (end_index == -1) end_index = line_text.Length;
            return line_text.Substring(start_index, end_index - start_index);
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Returns a decimal containing the element from the current segment.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="element_number">The element number that you want to return</param>
    public Decimal get_element_as_number(int element_number) {
        Decimal i = (Decimal.TryParse(get_element(element_number), out i)) ? i : 0;
        return i;
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Return added total of the elements within the segment.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="start">Element number to start adding.</param>
    ///<param name="step">Increment of element position after each add.</param>
    public Decimal get_elements_total(int start, int step) {
        Decimal total = 0;
        for (int i = start; i <= get_length(); i += step) {
            total += get_element_as_number(i);
        }
        return total;
    }

    public String get_id() {
        if (id != null) return id;
        int index = line_text.IndexOf(x12_reader.element_delimiter);
        if (index >= 0) {
            id = line_text.Substring(0, index);
            return id;
        }
        return String.Empty;
    }

    public int get_length() {
        int count = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < line_text.Length; i++) {
            if (line_text[i] == x12_reader.element_delimiter) count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Returns a segment with the selected element replaced with the string value passed.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="element_number">The element that you want to replace.</param>
    ///<param name="value">The string value with which you want to replace the element.</param>
    public segment replace_element(int element_number, String value) {
        String[] elements = line_text.Split(x12_reader.element_delimiter);
        if (element_number < elements.Length && element_number > 0) {
            elements[element_number] = value;
            segment return_segment = new segment();
            return_segment.line_text = String.Join(x12_reader.element_delimiter.ToString(), elements);
            return return_segment;
        }
        return this;
    }
}

public class transaction {
    public segment[] segments;

    ///<summary>
    //Returns true if the current transaction contains the id.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="id">The id to find.</param>
    ///<param name="in_loop">The loop to limit the search.</param>
    public bool contains_id(String id, String in_loop = null) {
        foreach (segment s in segments) {
            if (in_loop != null) {
                if (s.get_id() == id && s.loop_id == in_loop) return true;
            } else if (s.get_id() == id) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Returns the full text of the transaction as a String.
    ///</summary>
    public String get_full_text() {
        return get_lines(0, segments.Length - 1);
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Returns a String containing a section of a transaction.
    ///</summary>
    public String get_lines(int start, int end) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (end >= segments.Length) end = segments.Length - 1;
        if (start >= 0) {
            for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                sb.Append(segments[i].line_text);
                sb.AppendLine(x12_reader.line_terminator.ToString());
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        return "";
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Returns the first segment of the id type requested.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="id">ID of the segment to return.</param>
    ///<param name="element_1">First element of the ID to return.</param>
    public segment get_segment_of_type(String id, String element_1 = null) {
        foreach (segment s in segments) {
            if (s.get_id() == id) {
                if (element_1 != null) {
                    if (element_1 == s.get_element(1)) {
                        return s;
                    }
                } else {
                    return s;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Returns a List containing only segments with the corresponding id.
    ///</summary>
    public List<segment> get_segments_of_type(String id, String element_1 = null) {
        List<segment> temp_segment_list = new List<segment>();
        foreach (segment s in segments) {
            if (s.get_id() == id) {
                if (element_1 != null) {
                    if (element_1 == s.get_element(1)) {
                        temp_segment_list.Add(s);
                    }
                } else {
                    temp_segment_list.Add(s);
                }
            }
        }
        return temp_segment_list;
    }
}

public class x12_reader {
    public static Char element_delimiter;
    public static Char line_terminator;
    public static Char sub_delimiter;
    public segment GE;
    public segment GS;
    public Dictionary<String, Int32> id_counts = new Dictionary<String, Int32>();
    public segment IEA;
    public segment ISA;
    private FileStream file_stream;
    private StreamReader stream_reader;
    private StringBuilder string_builder = new StringBuilder();

    ///<summary>
    ///Class created to read and manage X12/EDI files.
    ///<param name="input">Path to the x12 file to be processed.</param>
    public x12_reader(String input) {
        file_stream = File.Open(input, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        stream_reader = new StreamReader(file_stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, false, 4096);

        line_terminator = read_char_at_location(105 + byte_order_mark_offset());
        sub_delimiter = read_char_at_location(104 + byte_order_mark_offset());
        element_delimiter = read_char_at_location(103 + byte_order_mark_offset());
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Returns the number for segments with the selected id.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="id">The segment id to count.</param>
    public int get_segment_count(String id) {
        if (id_counts.ContainsKey(id)) return id_counts[id];
        return 0;
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Builds the transactions list within the x12_reader class.
    ///</summary>
    public IEnumerable<transaction> read_x12(ProgressBar pBar = null) {
        MethodInvoker m = new MethodInvoker(() => pBar.Maximum = (int)stream_reader.BaseStream.Length);
        MethodInvoker v = new MethodInvoker(() => pBar.Value = (int)stream_reader.BaseStream.Position);

        int update_count = 0;
        List<segment> segments = new List<segment>();
        segment s;
        String current_loop = "";
        transaction t = new transaction();

        pBar.Invoke(m);
        using (stream_reader) {
            while (!stream_reader.EndOfStream) {
                update_count++;
                if (update_count >= 150000) {
                    pBar.Invoke(v);
                    update_count = 0;
                }

                s = get_segment();
                switch (s.get_id()) {
                    case "ISA":
                        ISA = s;
                        ISA.line_text = ISA.line_text.Substring(byte_order_mark_offset(), ISA.line_text.Length - byte_order_mark_offset());
                        ISA.loop_id = current_loop;
                        break;

                    case "IEA":
                        IEA = s;
                        IEA.loop_id = current_loop;
                        break;

                    case "GS":
                        GS = s;
                        GS.loop_id = current_loop;
                        break;

                    case "GE":
                        GE = s;
                        GE.loop_id = current_loop;
                        break;

                    case "ST":
                        current_loop = "";
                        s.loop_id = current_loop;
                        segments.Clear();
                        t = new transaction();
                        segments.Add(s);
                        break;

                    case "SE":
                        current_loop = "";
                        s.loop_id = current_loop;
                        segments.Add(s);
                        t.segments = segments.ToArray();
                        yield return t;
                        break;

                    case "N1":
                        if (s.get_element(1) == "PR") current_loop = "1000A";
                        if (s.get_element(1) == "PE") current_loop = "1000B";
                        s.loop_id = current_loop;
                        segments.Add(s);
                        break;

                    case "LX":
                        current_loop = "2000";
                        s.loop_id = current_loop;
                        segments.Add(s);
                        break;

                    case "CLP":
                        current_loop = "2100";
                        s.loop_id = current_loop;
                        segments.Add(s);
                        break;

                    case "SVC":
                        current_loop = "2110";
                        s.loop_id = current_loop;
                        segments.Add(s);
                        break;

                    case "PLB":
                        current_loop = "";
                        s.loop_id = current_loop;
                        segments.Add(s);
                        break;

                    default:
                        s.loop_id = current_loop;
                        segments.Add(s);
                        break;
                }
            }
            pBar.Invoke(v);
        }
    }

    private int byte_order_mark_offset() {
        if (read_char_at_location(0) == 0xEF &&
            read_char_at_location(1) == 0xBB &&
            read_char_at_location(2) == 0xBF) {
            return 3;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private segment get_segment() {
        segment segment = new segment();
        segment.line_text = read_line();
        increment_count_for_id(segment.get_id());
        return segment;
    }

    private void increment_count_for_id(String id) {
        int value = 0;
        if (!id_counts.TryGetValue(id, out value)) id_counts.Add(id, 0);
        id_counts[id]++;
    }

    private Char read_char_at_location(long location) {
        long old_location = file_stream.Position;
        file_stream.Position = location;
        if (file_stream.Position < file_stream.Length) {
            Char c = (char)file_stream.ReadByte();
            file_stream.Position = old_location;
            return c;
        }
        file_stream.Position = old_location;
        return '\0';
    }

    private String read_line() {
        string_builder.Clear();
        int n;
        while ((n = stream_reader.Read()) != -1) {
            if (n == line_terminator) return string_builder.ToString();
            string_builder.Append((char)n);
        }
        return string_builder.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

1. I can not make get_element() return multiple elements at once. The function     must return one element at at time.
2. I have already run a profiler. My choke points seem to be Substring and Stringbuilder.
3. I have already tried to reduce the amount of times I call get_element() and read_line() functions in my calling code. I do not think I can reduce the amount of calls any further.

Example of use:

```
x12_reader xr = new x12_reader(path_to_x12);

foreach (transaction t in xr.read_x12(_progressbar_all_processing)) {
        //Do something with the transaction
        foreach(segment s in t.segments){
               if(s.get_id() == "ID"){
                   s.get_element(5);
               }
        }
}
```

Alternate attempt at the get_element function. This ended up being slower but I may have done something in a sub-optimal way.

```
public string get_element_alt(int index) {
        var buffer = new StringBuilder();
        var counter = 0;

        using (var enumerator = line_text.GetEnumerator()) {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
                if (enumerator.Current == x12_reader.element_delimiter) {
                    counter++;
                } else if (counter == index) {
                    buffer.Append(enumerator.Current);
                } else if (counter > index)
                    break;
            }
        }
        return buffer.ToString();
    }
```

Before anyone flags this question and tells me to post it in Code Review. I have already done that and all I got was pedantic responses about my coding style.

Before anyone flags this question and says there are other posts concerning making code run faster I would pause and note that I am very specific on what I am trying to do and what kind of task I need to perform faster. I am not asking the general question "How do I write fast code."

Comment: Why do you need your own `read_line()`? Why can't you just use `stream_reader.ReadLine()`?

Comment: @Daniel, did you try to profile? It might give you some information.

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan *I have already run a profiler. My choke points seem to be Substring and Stringbuilder.*

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen -The file that I am reading has a special end line character, most of the time "~", that the built in readline function doesn't recognize. In short, there are no end of line characters in the file.

Comment: @Daniel, you need to implement caching. You are calling `get_element(int)` all over the place, effectively reading the same things again and again. Add a `private Dictionary<int, string> elements` to your `segment` class that maps element indeces to the element content. Now the first thing you do inside `get_element(int)` is to check whether `elements.TryGetValue(element_number, out element_content)` returns `true`. If so return `element_content` immdiately. Otherwise parse it like before, add it to the cache with `elements[element_number] = element_content` and return it.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I understand that caching is a good idea, and on get_id() I do cache, but chaching does me no good on get_element(). I almost never call get_element() twice for the same data. There are millions of calls. Every call is on different data, and almost never the same element.

Comment: Mkay... then avoid using `IndexOf()` and `Substring()` altogether by looping over the chars of the string with `for`. This way you stay in _O(n)_ land (with _n_ being the length of the string).

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I have tried to do that but then I need to use a StringBuilder to build up the string when I pass over the element that I need. This is even slower than what I am doing because StringBuilder is much slower than SubString. I thought that the method would be faster as well, but I implemented it and it ended up being slower.

Comment: Why do you _have_ to use a `StringBuilder`? Just append the chars with `+` to a string. Or create an array of chars that you turn into string in the end.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride String is immutable. using + would be so so much slower. There would be a new string allocation for each +, and the array of characters idea. I believe that is what StringBuilder does, I may be wrong.

Comment: AFAIK there is no real difference between `StringBuilder` and `+` anymore. Anyway, as long as you haven't tried the loop-over-chars-and-accumulate-result-as-array idea and gave us some numbers that show it's still to slow, there's not much we can do. There is no magic trick anyone could pull off. Have you thought about parallelization?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride, hm, but this [example](http://www.volatileread.com/utilitylibrary/snippetcompiler?id=75455) shows that there is difference.

Comment: Good to know, thanks.

Comment: How long is the typical line and is there a maximum line length?

Comment: @RBarryYoung - The length of the lines varies greatly. There is no maximum length.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following modification of my proposal in your previous question.

The idea is to cache the `StringBuilder` to avoid creating million of these objects. I find it hard to believe that this could perform worse than repeated calls to `IndexOf` and `Substring`.

```
StringBuiler buffer = new StringBuilder();

public string get_element(int index)
{
     var counter = -1;

     using (var enumerator = text_line.GetEnumerator())
     {
         buffer.Clear();

         while (enumerator.MoveNext())
         {
             if (enumerator.Current == x12_reader.element_delimiter)
             {
                 counter++;
             }
             else if (counter == index)
             {
                 buffer.Append(enumerator.Current);
             }
             else if (counter > index)
                 break;
        }
     }

     return buffer.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I have changed the get_element_alt to use a cached StringBuilder and the results on a 58mb x12 file are   get_element_alt version 6874ms / get_element_original version 5810ms. I don't know why it is slower but it is.

Comment: @Daniel Are you benchmarking in release mode and without debugger?

Comment: Yes, I am doing the benchmark in release mode. I would have thought that Stringbuilder would have been faster. I don't understand why your method is slower.

Comment: @Daniel if you have a good idea of the maximum length an element can get to be try tweeking the initial capacity of the `StringBuilder` to avoid the cost of allocating a new builder under the hoods.

Comment: The default capacity of StringBuilder is 16. I think this would be a good capacity for the average length of these elements but I tried several values larger and smaller and I still get around the same performance.

Comment: @Daniel The built string is probably too short to overcome the overhead of `StringBuilder`; simply concatenating strings is probably faster if the length is that small, the problem would be the memory pressure of instantiating that many strings when calling `get_element` so many times. It looks like using `Substring` might be the the fastest way.

Comment: I tried simple concatenation but that was even slower.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you use `GetEnumerator()` instead of `foreach`?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride - because it is faster.